# Can a driver be called/make calls if its device is disabled?

Tags: drivers

I have a question that I've been wondering the answer to for some time. For example, let's say a user has a Bluetooth driver present on their system with the name **12345.sys** for example purposes, and it's loaded. If the user disables the Bluetooth device in Device Manager, does that unload **12345.sys**, and stop it from making calls and/or being called?

I ask because as a kernel debugger, I have read in the past that software must be properly removed from either Control Panel's Add/Remove Programs list (or with a manufacturer removal tool) to unload drivers fully, as disabling the device may not fully unload the driver. I am wondering if this is actually the case.

Comment: Generally, yes it is the safest and most reliable way. Exceptions could be made, such as malware or poorly written software (Java!) where a good manual registry scrub is needed to clean out the odd bits.